# casting into a Python string from a char[] returned by a DLL

Tags: python, c, string, ctypes

I am attempting to cast a C style const char[] string pointer (returned from a DLL) into a Python compatible string type. but when Python27 executes:

```
import ctypes

charPtr = ctypes.cast( "HiThere", ctypes.c_char_p )
print( "charPtr = ", charPtr )
```

we get: `charPtr =  c_char_p('HiThere')`

perhaps something is not to be evaluating properly.
My questions are:

1. how should one cast this charPtr back into a Python compatible, print-able string?
2. is the cast operation just mentioned doing what it should be doing?

Answer (score 16):

ctypes.cast() is used to convert one ctype instance to another ctype datatype.
You don't need it To convert it to python string.
Just use ".value" to get it in python string.

```
>>> s = "Hello, World"
>>> c_s = c_char_p(s)
>>> print c_s
c_char_p('Hello, World')
>>> print c_s.value
Hello, World
```

More info [here](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html)

Answer (score 9):

If you set the [`argtypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) or [`restype`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types) attributes of [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) functions, they will return the right Python object without the need for a cast.

Here's an example calling the C-runtime `time` and `ctime` functions:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> m=CDLL('msvcrt')
>>> t=c_long(0)
>>> m.time(byref(t))
1326700130
>>> m.ctime(byref(t))  # restype not set
6952984
>>> m.ctime.restype=c_char_p  # set restype correctly
>>> m.ctime(byref(t))
'Sun Jan 15 23:48:50 2012\n'
```

Comment: @HelinWang no, it doesn't.  In this case `ctime` returns a pointer to static memory so there is nothing to manage.

Comment: Do you know about the general case? : c library returned a memory allocated on the heap.

Comment: @HelinWang Even in the general case, if C allocates it, C must free it.  In that case you don't want to use `c_char_p` either, because `ctypes` is "helpful" and converts it to a Python string.  You don't get the returned pointer so can't pass it to a ctypes-wrapped `free` function.  Use another type such as `POINTER(char)` or `c_void_p`, extract the string, then pass the pointer to `free` or the like.