# Python - how interpret memory address and size returned by DLL as byte array

Tags: python, memory-management, dll

Suppose `script.py` calls to *DLL* `func()` [written in C] using `ctypes`

`func()` returns 2 things:

1. Local virtual address of allocated `uint8_t` *array*
2. Size of this *array*

What is the best way to make a pythonic byte array or list from this `uint8_t` array, without memory copying. In the other words let Python know to treat the specified block of memory as pythonic byte array?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [casting into a Python string from a char\[\] returned by a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875185/casting-into-a-python-string-from-a-char-returned-by-a-dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if it works, but try this:

```
localAddress, arraySize = func()
yourByteArray = bytearray(ctypes.string_at(localAddress, arraySize))
```

Comment: Actually, `ctypes.string_at()` already returns with a `bytes` object, if you don't need `bytearray`. (It stands for Python 3.x., for Python 2.x, you need the bytearray() wrap, otherwise it returns with simple string.)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if string_at() copies memory or just represents it as byte array.