# Getting char array from c dll in python as string

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am a beginner with ctypes and I can not figure out how to turn char array into a string in python. I have started using :

`create_string_buffer(bytes(var, 'utf8'))` to populate an array, but had no luck with getting it back as a string using "byref()".

If someone has any idea you would be a life saver. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875185/casting-into-a-python-string-from-a-char-returned-by-a-dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ctypes* page: [[Python]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). 
It's hard to tell without seeing some code, but here's an example:

> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> import ctypes
> >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
> 'Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux'
> >>> src = "some dummy Python string"
> >>> src_charp = ctypes.create_string_buffer(src.encode())
> >>> dst_initial = b"Just "
> >>> dst_charp = ctypes.create_string_buffer(len(dst_initial) + len(src) + 1)
> >>> dst_charp
> <ctypes.c_char_Array_25 object at 0x7fe6c41209d8>
> >>> dst_charp.value
> b''
> >>> for idx, c in enumerate(dst_initial):
> ...     dst_charp[idx] = c
> ...
> >>> dst_charp.value
> b'Just '
> >>> ctypes.CDLL(None).strcat(dst_charp, src_charp)
> 32414128
> >>> dst_charp
> <ctypes.c_char_Array_25 object at 0x7fe6c41209d8>
> >>> dst_charp.value
> b'Just some dummy Python string'
> >>> dst = dst_charp.value.decode()
> >>> dst
> 'Just some dummy Python string'
> ```

**Notes**:

- Uses [[man7]: STRCAT(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) as an example. For more details on **how**, please check [[SO]: How does ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(None) work? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878901/how-does-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrarynone-work/49880922#49880922)
- There was no `byref` involved

Comment: The solution is quite ugly indeed :

cp = create_string_buffer(bytes("  <spaces of return value for example (20 spaces, chars...) stackoverflow just ignores the sapces>                   ", 'utf8'))  **<--- keep in mind the spaces**

and then getting it using `byref(cp)` from inside the function, you get the object

str(cp.value) finally returns the desired string/path

I have no idea why it works, so if someone could elaborate me a bit on this python madness i'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: So the argument is an inout one. I modified the code to reflect that. As I said at the beginning, it's hard to guess what happens in your case without any code. For a proper understanding, the *Python* code that calls the function should be available, and also the *C* function declaration.